# Problems with interpretation on a squared variable in multiple linear regression model

Tags: r, regression, self-study, linear-model

In my regression model I have a variable that goes from 0-40. I found that in order to achieve a correct functional form (based on RESET test), that variable should be squared.

So suppose my model is::

```
y=b0+b1x1+b2x1^2++ε
```

Partial derivate wil be:

```
b1+2β2x1
```

Now, solving for x1 we have:
    x1= -b1/2b2

With my current data this relation is:

```
x1= -0.4503687/(2*0.0165158)= -13.63448
```

This suppose to be a global minimum for the function at point -13.63448.

But the problem is that my variable goes from 0 to 40 with no negative value. So, how can I interpret this result? 
Any help appreciated

This is my regression output, maybe this could help a bit. The variable I refer to in this post is prom_sec. I must add that my dependent variable is also positive and goes from 0 to 128.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case the effect of `prom_sec` is positive for the entire range of your variable. When `prom_sec` is 0 then a unit increase in `prom_sec` corresponds to 0.45 units increase in the expected value of `puntaje`. However this effect of `prom_sec` increases by 0.017 for every unit increase in `prom_sec`. So at `prom_sec` is 40 a unit increase in `prom_sec` corresponds to a 1.13 unit increase in expected value of `puntaje`. You can think of a square term as an interaction term of a variable with itself ($x^2 = x\times x$)

Comment: So when prom=40 we have 40*(0.45 + (40*0.017))= 40*(0.44+0.68)= 40*1.13=45.2 Then the expected effect for prom=40 is 45.2 in puntaje. Am I right?

Comment: No, the effect of prom when prom =40 is 0.450 +40*0.017=1.13