# coefficient of Nonlinear relationship interpretation

Tags: regression, nonlinear

I try to identify a nolinear relationship between a dependent variable and independent varaibles. In the literature, to detect this relation, we introduce the term.
When I make a simple Regression ( OLS) with the introduction of variables (without their squared), the model gives not significant results, for the indépendents variables. On the other hand, it becomes significant, (similar for basic variables) when I add the square term.
The problem that I do not know how interpret the sign of the variable coefficient in  a  non linear relationship.

Comment: Maybe this post helps: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/313011/problems-with-interpretation-on-a-squared-variable-in-multiple-linear-regression/313025#313025

Answer (score 1):

First, adding a squared term is only one of many ways to look for a nonlinear relationship.

Second, don't over-rely on significance.

Now, to your question: There are various ways that a quadratic relationship can mask a linear one. I'll give an example with only one IV, for simplicity.  Suppose $Y = x^2 + e$ and x ranges from -10 to 10.  Then trying to fit a linear relationship will result in a coefficient near 0 (and a p value near 1).

If $y = x^2 + x + e$ then it's possible to get a nonsignificant linear relationship that becomes significant when the quadratic term is added.

Graphics can help interpret these models.